# Jenkins Confluence plublisher plugin usage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, confluence, jenkins-groovy

I tried Jenkins confluence publisher plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin

Could not understand what is "after token" "before token" etc. 
Here is what i am looking - From Jenkins job pipeline, i want to publish content in 4 sections on a confluence page
    1) Reviewers (we get from one of the pipeline step)
    2) Sonarqube report
    3) veracode report 
    4) bitbucket info
All 4 sections information is from previous pipeline steps - How do i publish as sections
Can you please give a sample example.

I tired with "first token" and got below error

````
[confluence] EXPERIMENTAL: performing storage format edits on Confluence 4.0
[confluence] Performing wiki edits: Insert content before token
[confluence] ERROR while performing replacement: Marker token could not be located in the page content: first token```
````